# Parts of paragraph style won't stick

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, paragraph-styles, formatting

I've got a problem where I am defining a paragraph style, but when I am applying it, it does everythin as defined except for the font style. It just applies a font style I did not select, however the font family is correct.

What is weird about it is, when I change it manually to the correct style, it works AND it doesn't even show that little "+" for modified paragraph styles.
Secondly there are NO character styles applied at all.
When I apply the right style manually, reapply any other style, it does the same thing. Hence, font family, size and everything works fine, except for the font style. 
Hope someone can help out here.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There must be an override, sometimes these are left over from previous formatting and difficult to spot. Try selecting a paragraph, go to the Paragraph Styles panel, right click your paragraph name and choose Apply + Clear overrides.

Also, make sure the style you intend to use is available (properly installed) in your system and is explicitly setup in the paragraph style — the exact naming must be used in the 'Font Syle' field of the paragraph style (for instance, if the style is called 'Book' and you're assuming it should be called 'Regular').